# JPA - Update binary data

Tags: jpa, hsqldb, binary-data

I am new to JPA and hibernate.

I am using HSQLDB 2.0 and hibernate-JPA to insert image into BINARY column. I have annotated as follows

```
@Lob
private byte[] profileImage;
```

I can insert the image into the database.

I am retrieving the entity from database along with the binary column and converting the byte array into Image.

But when I request to persist the entity again after an update, I am getting following error.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:54)
    ... 68 more
```

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: data exception: string data, right truncation
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
        ... 76 more

Can anyone please let me know what might be the issue?

Thank you in advance,

Regards,
Niranjan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the latest Hibernate 3.6.2 and HSQLDB 2.1.
Also, use a column of LONGVARBINARY or BLOB to store images. A BINARY column stores extra zero bytes after the image data to fill up its declared length, while the other two types do not add zero padding.